# How do I creating a simple Github Action to apend a datetime to a logfile and commit the change

Tags: webhooks, github-actions

I want to create a simple Github Action that logs a timestamp to a log file, to something like /logs/publish.log

I need the github action to trigger from a webhook.

My github action would upon receiving a webhook request.

1. Append the date/time to the end of /logs/publish.log
2. Do an automatic commit eg "Newly published content"

**How would I configure a github action to achieve this?**

Here's where I'm at as a start:

File: .github/workflows/log-commit-on-repository-dispatch.yml

```
    name: log-commit-on-repository-dispatch
    on: workflow_dispatch
    jobs:
      append-log-to-trigger-publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Append Current Date & Time to Log
            run: date >> /logs/publish.log 
            shell: bash
          - name: Commit change to log file
            run: git commit -am "Newly published content"
            shell: bash
```

Pretty sure my run is not correct and I need to refer to external actions.

**Why?** To deploy my headless CMS I need to trigger a commit on my github repo, which has the effect of recompiling my build and pulling in the latest from the headless CMS.

Comment: You're not checking out any repository, use `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` as a first step and `git push` your changes as a last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the essence of this solved with the clue provided by riQQ.
actions/checkout@v2 provided almost the exact code I needed in their example code to [Push a commit using the built-in token](http://Push%20a%20commit%20using%20the%20built-in%20token)

.github/workflows/publish.yml

```
name: publish
on: [workflow_dispatch, repository_dispatch]
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          date > published.txt
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m "Published Changes"
          git push
```